# Jpa ManyToMany relationships doesn't work

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have SpringBoot 2.1.3 + MySql 5.7 Database. I'm trying to do a ManyToMany relationship between 2 entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Hobby {
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "hobbies")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

now if I made a test:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("James");
user.setHobbies(new ArrayList<>());

Hobby hobby = new Hobby();
hobby.setDescription("Golf");
hobby.setUsers(new ArrayList<>());

user.getHobbies.add(hobby);
hobby.getUsers.add(user);

userRepository.save(user);
```

All three tables are persisted (User table, Hobby table and the mapping one created by jpa) as follows:

```
USER              USER_HOBBY               HOBBY
id, name          iduser, idhobby          id, description
1   James         1        1               1   Golf
```

But if now I call

```
List<User> us = userRepository.findAll();
```

inside *us* I don't have any hobby entities.. It said:

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

My application.properties with db config:

```
# Connection url for the database "test"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I have tried everything following all the examples find by google.
What's wrong??

Thank you

Comment: Hi, i have a small question, are duplicate hobbies allowed, imagine we have only predefined hobbies that user should select, how can be implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont save hobby entity before calling `userRepository.findAll()`.

If you create relationship between entities, you need to save all entity dependents before saving and searching global entity.

If you save entity whith NULL in dependents fields they dont throw exception. In your case you save empty list, but hibernate cant save, because his check FK and dont find this hobby.

You can try save user with NULL or with exists in database hobby. Like this:

```
List<Hobby> hobbies = hobbyRepository.findAll();

user.getHobbies().addAll(hobbies); // null pointer exception
userRepository.save(user);

userRepository.findAll();
```

I dont understand why your repository allows you to save. I use postgres and interface extends on JpaRepository and they throw exception if i save user with empty hobbies list.

---

I tryed with:

```
Hobby h = new Hobby();
h.setDesc("Golf");
hobbyRepository.save(h);

List<Hobby> hobbies = hobbyRepository.findAll();

Persona p = new Persona();
p.setNome("Giacomo");
p.setHobbies(new ArrayList<>());
p.getHobbies().addAll(hobbies);
personaRepository.save(p);

List<Persona> persone = personaRepository.findAll();
List<Hobby> hobby = hobbyRepository.findAll();
```

Doesn't work.. Can you made a working example similar to this one?? I will appreciate it because I can't understand where the error is..
P.S. If I put:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

It works.. but I don't wanna put it!! It should work with the default values..

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I will try to save everything before call the findAll() method but regarding your doubts maybe you have read wrong.. Nothing is null, I create empty ArrayList before call *user.getHobbies.add(hobby);* and *hobby.getUsers.add(user);* to avoid **NullPointerException** and I save user at the end. If you copy the whole code and try to test it will not throw any exception..

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It is a Session problem and there are different solution.

The first is adding fetch annotation:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
  private String name;
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Hobby> hobbies;
}
```

This way everytime you find User entity you will fetch all related Hobbies. Other solution (much better) is leave default fetch value (lazy for many to many relationships) and add *@Transactional* annotation on method you are using to retrieve data.

```
@Transactional
public void searchData() {
  User user = new User();
  user.setName("James");
  user.setHobbies(new ArrayList<>());

  Hobby hobby = new Hobby();
  hobby.setDescription("Golf");
  hobby.setUsers(new ArrayList<>());

  user.getHobbies.add(hobby);
  hobby.getUsers.add(user);

  userRepository.save(user);

  List<User> us = userRepository.findAll();
  for (User u : us) {
    System.out.println(u.getHobbies().size()); // print 1
  }
}
```

Hope helps..